# Magento catalog price rule grid not working

Tags: magento2.3, catalog-price-rules, promotions

I'm  unable to create catalog price rule and existing price rule too is not working in site. In console, I could see below error.

> uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of undefined
> at g.bindFieldsChange (grid.min.js:20)
> at g.initGrid (grid.min.js:7)
> at g.initialize (grid.min.js:3)
> at new g (legacy-build.min.js:1)
> at (index):160
> at Object.execCb (39daca1563231596c195ad22ae44a0ec.min.js:112)
> at Module.check (39daca1563231596c195ad22ae44a0ec.min.js:56)
> at Module. (39daca1563231596c195ad22ae44a0ec.min.js:72)
> at 39daca1563231596c195ad22ae44a0ec.min.js:11
> at 39daca1563231596c195ad22ae44a0ec.min.js:74

1. I tried redeploying, as it seems to be js issue.
2. I ensure no duplicate catalog rules in DB

Can some help me to identify issue and suggest for fix?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried to  run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogrule_product` command, I got below exception  and fixed issue by removing duplicate entries and re running indexer command. Hope it helps someone

> report.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Interceptor) with the same ID "9" already exists.